# sublime is not highlighting c++ files

Tags: c++, g++, sublimetext2

I set up sublime and my text is not showing up colorful or anything highlighted if a library, etc. I am doing a simple hello world and I am getting the error:

```
clang: error: no input files
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: It means you didn't save your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your files are saved and have the appropriate file extensions:
C/C++ common file extensions:
`.c`, `.cpp`, `.cc`, `.h`, `.hpp`

Also check that you have syntax highlighting enabled:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

```
Set Syntax: C++11
```

There is not enough information on your build system from within sublime.
Check `Tools->Build System` and make the necessary adjustments there.